On a tavern-style pizza, what is the relationship between the number of cuts and the area of the square slices?
On a tavern-style pizza, what is the relationship between the number of cuts $C$ and the area of the square slices $P$ (for "piece", maybe)?
For this tavern-style pizza, assume:

The number of vertical slices is equal to the number of horizontal slices (this is not always true, but assume).
The number of cuts $C$ always evenly divides the diameter into $C + 1$ equal lengths.
The pizza is a circle.
Any "horizontal" cut is at perpendicular to any "vertical" cut.

Do not assume:

There is a square inscribed in the circle. If you look at tavern-style pizzas, this is usually not the case.
One of the cuts bisects the pizza. This seems to usually be true, but not always.

For bonus points:

What if the number of horizontal cuts $H$ and vertical cuts $V$ are not the same?
What are the areas of the unique edge pieces in terms of $P$?

So, in other words, I'm hoping for a formula where you could enter the radius/diameter of the pizza and the number of cuts and have it produce the area of the square pieces produced by the intersecting cuts.
I am not a math person, and I am too old for homework. I can't even figure out where to get started with this, and ChatGPT's answer seems sketchy. I was frustrated that I couldn't quite gauge how much pizza I was eating with this odd Midwestern cut, which led me to this interesting puzzle. To clarify, I'm more interested in the puzzle at this point; it just seems like the kind of thing where there ought to be an answer. Any help is appreciated.

Since the $C$ cuts evenly divide the diameter $D$ into $C+1$ equal lengths, the size of these lengths is $\frac{D}{C+1}$. So the area of the square pieces is $$P=\frac{D^2}{(C+1)^2}.$$ Note that this is only valid for $C>1$. One cut in each direction creates four corner pieces and no central square pieces; for $C$ cuts, there are $(C-1)^2$ square pieces. Also note that a cut will always bisect the pizza whenever $C$ is odd, but when $C$ is even the pizza will not be bisected.
If the number of cuts aren't equal but are $C_H$ and $C_V$ then the formula becomes $$P=\frac{D^2}{(C_H+1)(C_V+1)}.$$ Similarly, both $C_H$ and $C_V$ need to be greater than $1$; the number of rectangular pieces is $(C_H-1)(C_V-1)$.
The edge pieces are trickier and require some harder maths (sorry). I'm having fun trying to solve this part of the problem but it's quite complicated; I'll include it in a separate answer. Edit this is incredibly complex so I'm not going to post anything more about it.
Edit: when saying how many rectangular pieces there would be, I assumed the number of cuts was such that the topmost/bottommost/leftmost/rightmost cut intersects all of the perpendicular cuts, i.e.
But if this is not the case, the answer is more complicated. E.g. for $C=10$ horizontal and vertical cuts, there are only $69$ square pieces: 

Thank you so much for exploring this! I think it is a very interesting problem and I appreciate your solution to the square pieces, that makes a lot of sense. I see what you mean about how there can quickly become a great number and variety of "edge" or unique pieces. I can't imagine how to approach it from a mathematical perspective; perhaps it's more of a computer science question at that point.

My approach was to take double integrals after using the equation for a circle and calculating equations for the lines made by the cuts. Even just for the simple corner pieces formed by a small number of cuts it was quite a long process!

I suspect some combination of mathematics and computer science would help; you can figure out a general form for the area of corner edge pieces and "top" edge pieces-noting that there's always a 2-way symmetry (or 4 if $C_H=C_V$)- using mathematics and you can figure out the values for the boundaries using code
